Save current state of the Kepler map from iframe to my Flask app
I'm loading kepler map on an iframe. How can I fetch all the changes that user is making in the kepler map on my backend? Essentially, I want to fetch the current state of the map after user has applied his changes(eg. filter, color changes, etc.)
kepler_load.html
<html>   
  <head>   
    <title>Kepler HeatMap</title>  
    <style>
      iframe{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style> 
  </head>   
  <body>   
    <div class="kepler-frame" id="kepler-frame">
      <button class="btn-save">Save</button>  
      <iframe src="{{ url_for('empty_map') }}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

app.py:
from keplergl import KeplerGl
import pandas as pd
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file, redirect, url_for, session, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

map_1 = KeplerGl(height=800)
data_file = pd.read_csv('kepler_shapes.csv')
map_1.add_data(data=data_file, name='data_1')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('kepler_load.html')

@app.route('/empty_map')
def empty_map():
    return map_1._repr_html_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


I've tried some methods but it is just able to download the map which I had sent from backend, not the updated map(changes made by user). I want to grab those changes in the backend.
